# List of figures to be gathered per week

Tags: sql

I have 3 SQL tables:

1. `Stores` (A list of stores with store code)
2. `Issues` (A list of issues past and present each store has had. Includes store code and a current flag if the issue is ongoing)
3. `Figures` (A list of figures for each store for each week)

I want to create a query that looks up the list of stores with current issues and given the week number, will provide a list of stores that I need to gain the figures for.

What I have:

```
SELECT "Stores"."Area", "Stores"."Store", "Stores"."Name"
FROM "Issues", "Stores", "Figures"
WHERE "Issues"."Store" = "Stores"."Store"
  AND "Figures"."Store Number" = "Issues"."Store"
  AND "Issues"."Current" = TRUE
  AND "Figures"."Week" <> '48'
```

The list I get back from this is all the entries from the figures table that don't equal week 48.

What I would like is a list of stores that dont have week 48 figures.

Any push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Tip 1, modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Tip 2, table aliases. (Tip 3, `"Current" IS TRUE` is the ANSI SQL syntax. Tip 4, have integer type columns for integer values.)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (in my assumption "Issues"."Current" is BIT field)

```
SELECT f.[Week], s.Area, s.Store, s.Name, i.*
FROM [Stores] as s
INNER JOIN [Issues] as i ON s.Store = i.Store
INNER JOIN [Figures] as f ON s.Store = f.Store Number
WHERE i.[Current] != 0;
```